# Shopware 6 - alternative to "bin/build-administration.sh" command

Tags: php, node.js, shopware

I have a plugin that exports the orders from the backend with information like name, articles, price, etc... 
In the dev shop I use the command **bin/build-administration.sh** to actually see the new changes that were made. 
After that I transfer it into the live shop and in there I can't see the new changes, because our hoster doesn't offer node.js and therefore I can't execute the command.

Is there any alternative so that I can see the changes of the plugin in the live shop?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the administration in your dev environment. In your plugin will be a public folder created. When you ship and install your plugin with this public folder into your live environment, it will be work without node.

**EDIT:**

you would also need to:

1. deactivate&deinstall the plugin
2. clear the caches
3. install&activate again

Comment: I copied the public folder from /src/Resources/ and put it into the plugin in the live shop but that doesn't work. I also uninstalled this plugin and put in the public folder before installing it again.

Answer (score 0):

1. change version number in your plugin **composer.json**
2. clear the cache
3. run **bin/console plugin:refresh**
4. run **bin/console plugin:update**
5. finish